# RegEx Get text between two newline

Tags: c++, regex

Hello I need get all text between **\r\r\n**

For example:

```
AT+CGPADDR= 1

+CGPADDR:"1 10.111.002.137

OK
```

[Image with enabled ASCII symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UfgP.png) 
For example:

```
AT+CGPADDR= 1\r\r\n
+CGPADDR:"1 10.111.002.137\r\n\r\n
OK\r\n
```

## And I wanted to get this:

```
+CGPADDR:"1 10.111.002.137
```

I've prepared something like this `\v(.+?)\v`, but it's not working as it should:
https://regex101.com/r/X6oPgu/1

Comment: Your value is in the first capturing group. If it did not work in the code, could you add it to the question?

Comment: In C++ `std::regex` you can't use `\v`. You may actually split the string with a `[\r\n]+` and grab the second item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ `std::regex` does not support the `\v` construct. You may match `\r\n\n` and match the line after it and capture into Group 1 with `(.+)`, and - if you want - match the line breaks, too:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::regex reg{"\r\r\n(.+)\r\n\r\n"};
    std::string text{"AT+CGPADDR= 1\r\r\n+CGPADDR:\"1 10.111.002.137\r\n\r\nOK\r\n"};
    std::smatch match;
    if (regex_search(text, match, reg)) {
        std::cout << match.str(1); // => +CGPADDR:"1 10.111.002.137
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/DH1RsL).

Note the `.` won't match any line break chars, so it is safe to use a greedy `+` (*1 or more*) quantifier.